# QuickBlox: Send messages is not updated on other devices with same login

Tags: android, ios, xampp, webrtc, quickblox

**User1**: Logged in on 2 devices

**User2**: Logged in on 1 device

**User1-device1** send message to **User2** - message goes fine.

But **User1-device2** don't get any notification about that message being send.

How to handle this? Same question applies to call.

I need this behavior on iOS and Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Message Carbons it's exactly what you need

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Message_carbons

http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Message_carbons

http://quickblox.com/developers/Web_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Message_carbons

Comment: Thanks @Igor - Just wondering how we can do the same with audio/video call? Thanks.